# how to publish(File system publish) Angular 2 web application from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, publish

I have created a simple app using angular 2 in Visual studio 2015. I want to publish it by using visual studio publish (File system Publish) option.

I would like to go with angular CLI, but don't know how to do that.
I have downloaded the sample project from angular Web site. https://nodejs.org/en/download. Then Created an empty web application in visual studio 2015.Added src folder, bs-config, package and tslint from the sample project.  Restore Packages (Right click package.json -> Restore Packages). Now to make it work within VS2015 i have done some changes. in index.html href="/src/" , /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js, /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js and /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js. And in system.config.js 'npm': '/node_module'.
after that I have added some components and have done some routing as well.

Comment: How do you build your angular application? With webpack manually? Angular Cli? First identify how you are building it yourself, then try to put it into a build step in your csproj/msbuild file. If you need help with that, try to give some more info on your current build process

Comment: Hi Fredrik,I would like to go with angular CLI, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hi Fredrik, I would like to go with CLI.